# loose the view of everything in the view port blender 2.80

Tags: 3d-view

This is about the 4th or 5th time this has happened to me:

I have set the view length quite high so to not lose half my model in the viewport.
After a while, when I view the model and turn a little, everything disappears. The only way to get it to appear again is to click on the camera. But if I then move the camera, the same happens again. And from then on I cannot move around the window.

I have tried adding a new camera which works to begin with, but not for long.
It's as though the mouse has been sped up and when I move it to the left or right I lose sight of everything. I have even tried resizing the model. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). Please, [upload your .blend file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can take a look (try to make it as small as possible).

Comment: Welcome to the site! As of now, your question is hard to understand. As @JachymMichal suggested, could you maybe upload a stripped down version of your .blend file? Also, try to add images (or even better GIFs) to the post and explain what you're doing more in detail. For example, what do you mean by "moving around the window"?